# Join databases in many services

Tags: microservices

I have three services, each of which has its own databases

- User information table located in service one database.
- The membership table located in the database of Service Two, which specifies which company the user belongs to.
- The table of financial information that is located in the database of
  Service Three.

**The challenge ahead:**

I want to return the user information of a company along with financial documents. Because the number of users may be over 20,000 and the number of financial documents of users over 400,000 records, it seems the best solution is to join the tables of each of the three services together. Is it correct to join these tables at any time when we want to get a financial report? Is there a better solution to increase the speed of receiving information?

I read [this article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/aggregator-microservice-design-pattern-998609f498d6). In this article it is said about Aggregator. What pattern do you suggest for this microservice architecture?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some misconceptions in this post about what "correctness" means, how to evaluate what's "best", and which of your questions needs to be part of your own requirements analysis (hence cannot be answered by our community).

> "it seems the best solution is to join the tables of each of the three services together."*

If the task is to return a joined report, it is not the "best" solution, it is simply the *required* solution. Note I am using the word "join" in the general meaning, not sure if you meant the same, or had a particular implementation in mind with some `JOIN` command in a relational database.

> *"Is it correct to join these tables at any time when we want to get a financial report?"*

If a financial report requires the joined data, then producing a  correct result will necessarily require to join the data together. However, if this is also correct in regards to performance and consistency, depends on what you precisely mean by *"join any time when we want ..."*, it depends how frequent that is, which consistency and performance requirements you have, how fast your actual implementation of that idea is and if your implementation meets those consistency and performance requirements (which only you can tell us).

> Is there a better solution to increase the speed of receiving information?

This question implies that "increasing the speed" is necessarily "better", which is - allow me to speak frankly - nonsense. Getting more speed is always a trade-off with investing more other resources (memory, storage, development effort). The best solution is the one which meets your performance requirements with the least effort and costs.

You probably wanted to ask "Is there *another* solution which might increase the speed of receiving information?". Well, from your question is not really clear what you current solution is, but let me explain your options.

Your task requires to join all the data somewhere together, maybe redundantly. This could happen "ad-hoc", whenever the data is queried, or in advance. The joining might happen once per night, once per month, once per minute (maybe by synchronous updates), whatever your requirements for "up-to-dateness" are. The place where this could happen can be one of the existing microservices (probably the one which currently stores the most of the data), or a fourth service specificially designed for reporting (an aggregator). Or you give up the idea of separate databases for each microservice and redesign to a central database.

Each of the solutions will have different trade-offs for consistency, availability, actuality of the data, resource requirements, development effort, and - last but not least- query speed. The "best" solution is the one which meets all of these requirements best (which only you know, not we), which is not necessarily the fastest solution.